# How to find if there are words repeated twice in a row

Tags: php, mysql

For example i have the below paragraph in a MySQL database table field

"The cutting off of the illumination of an astronomical object object, as in an eclipse of the Moon, when the Earth comes between"

Here the word "**object**" appears twice in a row (next to each other).

I want to check if this case appears in other records in same table. Is there an easy way to do this using PHP and MySQL

Comment: Just a hint. You could do this in either MySQL or PHP with regular expressions.

Comment: i found the pattern for preg_match "/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/" which works exactly the way i wanted.
Thank you all for helping me out..

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/\\b(\\w+)\\s\\1\\b/', $subject)) {
    //has repetition
}
```

Comment: i found the pattern for preg_match "/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/" which works exactly the way i wanted.
Thank you all for helping me out..

Answer (score 1):

This regex works: `(\b\w+\b)(?=\s?\1)` (see [example](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=2e004cbd))

To make it work in MySQL, the Word Boundaries (`\b`) must be replaced with MySQL equivalent `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, and `\w` with `[[:alnum:]]`:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE your_field REGEXP '([[:<:]][[:alnum:]]+[[:>:]])(?=\\s?\\1)';
```

But this query gives an error because, as Matt said,  MySQL [does not support backreferences](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29590). So, it's not possible with the current MySQL REGEXP.

Comment: i found the pattern for preg_match "/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/" which works exactly the way i wanted.
Thank you all for helping me out..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex for your purposes:

```
(\b\w+)(?:\s+\1)+
```

or

```
\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+
```

This will match any number of repeated words, with any amount of whitespace between words.

Do note that, depending on how the MySQL or PHP regex engine works (whichever one you use), the backslashes (and possibly parentheses) may need to be escaped, and you'll need to use whatever delimiters the regex engine uses for patterns. (Though if MySQL does not permit backreferences as Matt states, then you'll just have to use PHP for that.)

EDIT: Updated with word boundary check; didn't realize that `\w` doesn't do word boundary checking automatically for preg patterns.

Comment: i found the pattern for preg_match "/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/" which works exactly the way i wanted.
Thank you all for helping me out..

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP 'search term'

Will return rows that contain the appropriate term.

Comment: i found the pattern for preg_match "/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/" which works exactly the way i wanted.
Thank you all for helping me out..

Answer (score -1):

what about

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourfield LIKE "%yourword%%yourword%"
```

in my fast testcase on localhost, it worked.

Comment: Even though this probably would work, i don't recomend using it on large tables!! And a single % in the middle should be enough!

Comment: i dont know the words to look for

Comment: i found the pattern for preg_match "/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/" which works exactly the way i wanted.
Thank you all for helping me out..