# count the repeated words in the paragraph or file using ruby on rails or PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

Anybody know, how to count the repeated words in the paragraph/file using PHP or Ruby on Rails, without using the looping structure. I appreciate, very shortest and performance wise speedup answer.

Thanks

Comment: with regular expressions you can find the first occurrence of a match or return if there is a match (boolean) - but not how many times there is a match.  Without a loop anyways... in PHP.

Comment: Yeah, i know the regular expression technique. But, it's enough only for short string or simple file. But, i need to process with very big string or very big file nearly (50 mb) or above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP Array Functions**

```
$text = "apple, orange: banana. apple sausage bear orange";

$all_words = str_word_count($text, 1);
$unique_words = array_unique($all_words);
$repeated_words = array_diff_assoc($all_words, $unique_words);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($repeated_words);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => apple
    [6] => orange
)
```

Single function:

```
function repeatWords($text)
{
    $all_words = str_word_count($text, 1);
    $unique_words = array_unique($all_words);
    return array_diff_assoc($all_words, $unique_words);
}
```

Comment: Wow!.. This is exactly what i need. thanks @Geoffey. Can you reduce the using of three functions as one. i.e Is there any single php function available to fullfill my requirements.

Comment: @Mr. Black, I have edited my answer to add a single function.

Answer (score 4):

In ruby using the text in a comment above

```
our_string = "Dog, as a devil deified, lived as a god."
our_string.strip.downcase.split(/[^\w']+/).group_by(&:to_s).map{|w| {w[0]=>w[1].count}} 

=> [{"a"=>2}, {"devil"=>1}, {"god"=>1}, {"lived"=>1}, {"dog"=>1}, {"as"=>2}, {"deified"=>1}]
```

Comment: you can also use "tally" here

`our_string.strip.downcase.split(/[^\w']+/).tally`

Answer (score 0):

try this link:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

OR

[How to find if there are words repeated twice in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093982/how-to-find-if-there-are-words-repeated-twice-in-a-row)

Update:

May be this link work for u

http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/ruby/ruby-count-number-of-times-words-appear-in-text-file

Comment: thanks @Ashish. I thing you didn't understand my questions in correct way. The above function only count the number of words in the given string. in breif: "Dog, as a devil deified, lived as a god." this is the simple string. I need to count the word "as". The actual output is "as" => 2. like this, i need to process very big file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I've found is (using a loop).
This is over simplified, you can use preg_match to do case-insensitive matches.
This will work on a very large string as well.

```
$i=0;
$string = explode("The red fox is a fox");
foreach ($string as $s) {
  if (preg_match("/fox/i",$s) {
    $i++;
  }
}
$string = implode($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the word you're looking for, you probably need a hashmap. so you loop through the whole file in O(n) and save every word in it. I think everything else is slower.
maybe you get into trouble with the hashmap, if the file is really big.